# MySQL's alternative to T-SQL's WITH TIES

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table from which I want to get the top N records. The records are ordered by values and some records have the same values. What I'd like to do here is to get a list of top N records, including the tied ones. This is what's in the table:

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  | Value  |
+-------+--------+
| A     | 10     |
| B     | 30     |
| C     | 40     |
| D     | 40     |
| E     | 20     |
| F     | 50     |
+-------+--------+
```

Now if I want to get the top 3 like so

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Value DESC LIMIT 3
```

I get this:

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  | Value  |
+-------+--------+
| F     | 50     |
| C     | 40     |
| D     | 40     |
+-------+--------+
```

What I would like to get is this

```
+-------+--------+
| Name  | Value  |
+-------+--------+
| F     | 50     |
| C     | 40     |
| D     | 40     |
| B     | 30     |
+-------+--------+
```

I calculate the rank of each record so what I would really like is to get the first N ranked records instead of the first N records ordered by value. This is how I calculate the rank:

```
SELECT Value AS Val, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Value))+1 FROM table WHERE Value > Val) as Rank
```

In T-SQL something like this is achievable by doing this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 FROM table ORDER BY Value WITH TIES
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in MySQL? I understand it could be done with subqueries or temporary tables but I don't have enough knowledge to accomplish this. I'd prefer a solution without using temporary tables.

Comment: For your information, `WITH TIES` does not do what you describe (and want). It only includes ties in the last cut, does not return all distinct (X) values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
select Name, Value from table where Value in (
    select distinct Value from table order by Value desc limit 3
) order by Value desc
```

Or perhaps:

```
select a.Name, a.Value 
from table a
join (select distinct Value from table order by Value desc limit 3) b
     on a.Value = b.Value
```

Comment: No, I'm getting this:

#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: I added another possible variation.. give that a shot.

Comment: @brozo use join

Answer (score 5):

Starting with MySQL 8, you can use window functions to emulate the `WITH TIES` semantics, by filtering on `RANK()`. For example:

```
SELECT Name, Value
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Value, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Value DESC) AS rk
  FROM table
) t
WHERE rk <= 3
```

Note that when reading your question more closely, this doesn't do exactly what you seem to want, but it does exactly what T-SQL can do through the `TOP n WITH TIES` clause.

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.Name, a.Value 
from table a
join (select Value from table order by Value desc limit 3) b
     on a.Value = b.Value
```

This is like @Fosco's answer, but without `DISTINCT` in the subquery. His version returns the players with the top N scores, not the top N players (plus ties). E.g. if the scores are 50, 50, 50, 40, 40, 30, 20, he'll return 6 players (3x50, 2x40, 1x30), but you presumably just want 3x50.

Comment: This answer gives the same as the SQL-Server's `WITH TIES` (but it seems the OP does not want this.)

Comment: Hmm, that's right. I didn't notice that the tie he included in his sample was in the 2nd place. That's a pretty strange thing to want (which is why `WITH TIES` works the way it does).

Comment: Wikipedia calls it **Dense ranking**: **[Ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking)**

Comment: Thanks for some additional info on this! It's been a while since I fiddled around with this, and since then I managed to improve my SQL skills significantly. As to answer why I needed this "strange" kind of ranking: I was ranking a dataset of users and wanted to paginate the result. I wanted to break the list at a specific point regarding the rank (say first N) and not regarding the line count (N lines). So basically, I wanted to display the top N scores and their affiliated users which doesn't mean it will produce N lines - it could produce more than N lines, since scores can be repeated.