# How to count using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a list with the company that scans the most things... I've got two tables, `Exhibitors` and `Leads`

`Leads` contain each "action" that every exhibitors does. Sometimes, in the `Exhibitors` table, there's two accounts for the same company. For example, PepsiCO might have two accounts.

The key/col that link both is called `ExhibitorID`.

I need to retrieve the top 20 with the most leads (so COUNT(*) in `leads`) but I need to group by Company in `Exhibitors` table.

Curerntly I am using this :

```
    SELECT t2.ExhibitorID, t2.Company, t2.Username, t1.Count 
      FROM exhibitors AS t2
         , ( SELECT ExhibitorID, COUNT( * ) AS Count 
               FROM leads AS l 
              WHERE l.ContractorID = 100 
                AND l.ShowID =  "20120228AB" 
              GROUP BY l.ExhibitorID 
              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
              LIMIT 20 ) AS t1 
     WHERE t2.ExhibitorID = t1.ExhibitorID 
     ORDER BY t1.Count DESC
```

But it doesn't group by company. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: first off, I would change your query to use proper ANSI JOIN syntax.  INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Additionally, I don't think you want a `LEFT JOIN` since you would get nulls for leads (or exhibitors) which won't count anyway. I think you're looking for `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @swasheck Unless there's the possibility for companies to have 0 associated leads, and he wants to get the 0 count for that company returned... in which case he would want a `left join`.

Comment: True, but he wants the top 20 leads. If he wants 0 leads to be in the top 20 then I guess it's ok, but that doesn't really seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on what the expected counts would be... if there will never be a 0 in the top 20, then `inner join`... if there could be a 0 in the top 20, then `left join`.

Comment: Top 20 has to be > 0 so I will use Inner... thanks a lot guys, very helpful !

Comment: Just FYI, with `INNER JOIN` if you do not have 20 non-zero results, you will only retrieve the number of matched results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    e.Company,
    COUNT(l.LeadId) AS Actions
FROM
    Exhibitors AS e 
    LEFT JOIN Leads AS l
        ON l.ExhibitorID = e.ExhibitorID
        AND l.ContractorID = 100
        AND l.ShowID = "20120228AB"
GROUP BY e.Company
ORDER BY Actions DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: good query, but `LEFT JOIN` will return NULL values for unmatched values of `Exhibitors`. MySql will ignore the NULL values for aggregate functions, but I think that `INNER JOIN` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @swasheck What if an exhibitor has no matching leads?  I think he would want to include a count of 0 in that case, instead of omitting the exhibitor from the result set.

Comment: Thanks:) I'll use INNER JOIN ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
    select e.exhibitorid, count(l.leadid) 
    from leads l 
        inner join exhibitors on e.exhibitorid = l.exhibitorid 
        and l.showid = "20120228AB" and l.contractorid = 100
    group by e.exhibitorid 
    order by count(l.contractorid) DESC
    limit 20;
```

If there are ties, this will still only return the top 20. So if you want ties then there appears to be a MySql workaround here [MySQL's alternative to T-SQL's WITH TIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties)

Answer (score 0):

You could group on Company and join on ExhibitorID:

```
select  e.Company
,       count(distinct l.LeadID) as LeadCount
from    Exhibitors e
join    Leads l
on      l.ExhibitorID = e.ExhibitorID
        and l.ShowID = "20120228AB" 
        and l.ContractorID = 100
group by
        e.Company
order by
        LeadCount DESC
limit   20
```