# MAX function without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID | NUM
 1 |  4
 2 |  9
 3 |  1
 4 |  7
 5 |  10
```

I want a result of:

```
ID | NUM
 5 | 10
```

When I try to use MAX(NUM) I get and error that I have to use GROUP BY in order to use MAX function

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want max of? `ID` or `NUM`?

Comment: I want the MAX of Num, but I also want to know the ID.

Comment: Example might be better if you chop off 5, 10 and have 2, 9 as expected result. Also, what if two rows share a MAX(num)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the error, use of an aggregate like `Max` requires a `Group By` clause if there are any non-aggregated columns in the select list (In your case, you are trying to find the `MAX(Num)` and then return the value(s) associated in the `ID` column). In MS SQL Server you can get what you want via ordering and limiting the returned rows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, NUM 
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY NUM DESC;
```

In other RDBMS systems the `LIMIT` offers similar functionality.

**Edit**

If you need to return all rows which have the same maximum, then use the [`WITH TIES` qualification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID, NUM 
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY NUM DESC;
```

Comment: How would it look like for MySQL (where there is no `TOP`)?

Comment: My question was more about the second part of the question, where I want to get all rows with maximal value

Comment: `WITH TIES` doesn't appear to be part of ANSI SQL. The common workaround seems to be to self-join on the highest value and then limit the result:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469107

Answer (score 9):

May return more than 1 result:

```
SELECT id, num
  FROM table
  WHERE num = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this query.

```
    WITH result AS 
    (
      select DENSE_RANK() OVER(  ORDER BY NUM desc) AS RowNo,ID,NUM from #emp 
     )
    select ID,NUM from result where RowNo=1
```

it will return max values even if it has more MAX values like:

```
ID | NUM
 5 | 10
 6 | 10
```

refer below link to know more about RANKING Functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID,NUM FROM table ORDER BY NUM DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this -

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID,
       NUM
FROM <yourtable>
ORDER BY NUM DESC;
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I hope you know that the questioner can edit his question. Why do you think there where 3 answers with `LIMIT`?

Comment: Sorry, I came here 5 hours later, and see no evidence of any edits to the question. Obviously if I see LIMIT answers I shouldn't just let them stay since they're incorrect, right? Thanks for correcting but now it's just a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Get all rows have max values but THERE ARE 3 SELECT, It's not good for performance

```
SELECT id, MAX(num) as num
FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MAX(num) DESC
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM table 
       WHERE num =(SELECT MAX(num) FROM table)
       )
```

Comment: This question is tagged SQL Server, there is no `LIMIT`