# Select Top N rows and also handle tie situation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get Top 3 row from the table but it should also consider tie situation.

I have a table which looks like this

```
+--------+---------+
| NAME   | COST    |
+--------+---------+
| EA     | 500     |
| SPSD   | 475     |
| IA     | 450     |
| NST    | 450     |
| AAD    | 350     |
| ECOM   | 325     |
+--------+---------+
```

And my desired result should look like this

```
+--------+---------+
| NAME   | COST    |
+--------+---------+
| EA     | 500     |
| SPSD   | 475     |
| IA     | 450     |
| NST    | 450     |
+--------+---------+
```

My Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY COST DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

But it returns only first 3 rows and doesn't handle if the 4th row is equal to 3rd.
How can I handle this situation from the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query to get the third highest cost:

```
select * from table
where cost >= (SELECT COST FROM TABLE
               ORDER BY COST DESC
               LIMIT 3,1)
ORDER BY c_cost DESC
```

(I'm not fully sure about the `LIMIT 3,1` part, since I'm not a MySQL guy. Test and see!)

Comment: Thanks @jarlh it worked

just had to add this to the query and it was perfect

`select * from COURSE
where c_cost >= (SELECT c_cost FROM COURSE
               ORDER BY c_cost DESC
               LIMIT 3,1)
ORDER BY c_cost DESC`

Comment: Good to hear it worked. Have now added the order by to my answer.

Comment: It would need a distinct in the subquery to handle ties, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using rank mechanism.
Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from test1 ;
+------+------+
| name | cost |
+------+------+
| EA   |  500 |
| SPSD |  475 |
| IA   |  450 |
| NST  |  450 |
| AAD  |  350 |
| ECOM |  325 |
+------+------+

select 
name,
cost from(
 select
 t1.*, 
 @rn:= if(@prev_cost = cost,@rn,@rn+1) as rn,
 @prev_cost:= cost 
 from test1 t1,(select @rn:=0,@prev_cost:=0)x
 order by cost desc 
)x
where x.rn <=3 ;

+------+------+
| name | cost |
+------+------+
| EA   |  500 |
| SPSD |  475 |
| IA   |  450 |
| NST  |  450 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT NAME, COST FROM TABLE WHERE COST IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT COST FROM TABLE ORDER BY COST DESC LIMIT 3
) ORDER BY COST DESC
```

Comment: But if there are 3 rows with highest cost, your query will return those 3 plus 2 extra. (Remove DISTINCT from sub-query to return just max 3.)