# Getting the Top N Results Including Ties

Tags: mysql

I’m working on a rec league website and want to have the top scorers in different categories listed.  That is easy enough, but if I am going for the top five point scorers for a category, and have 1st and 2nd, but then a three way tie for 3rd, is there a way to show that?

```
Ex:
Top 3 in Points
1 - Player A (10 pts)
2 – Player B (9 pts)
T3 – Player C (8 pts)
T3 – Player D (8 pts)
T3 – Player E (8 pts)
```

Top x percent won’t work either as new players come into the league and I’d rather not have to redo the calculations for each player addition.

Comment: So you just want the top 5 scorers, regardless of ties? Or if 5th place is a tie, you want only one of them?

Comment: No, I want the top three scorers, but since third place is a three way tie, I want five returned results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL's alternative to T-SQL's WITH TIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your table structure so I'm going to make some assumptions here, so adjust the table and column names as needed.

The first step would be get the top 3 scores:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `score`
FROM 
    `points` 
LIMIT 3
```

Then get all people with those scores, so putting it together gets:

```
SELECT
    `name`, -- Whichever fields you have
    `score`
FROM
   `points`
WHERE
    `score` IN (
         SELECT DISTINCT
             `score`
         FROM 
             `points` 
         LIMIT 3
    )
ORDER BY
    `points` DESC, -- Sort highest score first
    `name` ASC; -- When tied, sort alphabetically
```