# MySQL - Find MAX of grouped SUM (without LIMIT)

Tags: mysql

I would like to get the `user_id` and the sum of amount for the users who have largest summed amount. I cannot use `LIMIT` because that will return only 1 record (summed amount may be same for multiple users)

Here is my data schema and some records

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, 
  amount FLOAT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, amount) VALUES 
(1, 1000),
(1, 1000),
(1, 1000),
(2, 2000),
(2, 1000),
(3, 1000);
```

Here are the expected result.

```
+---------+------+
| user_id | sum  |
+---------+------+
|       1 | 3000 |
|       2 | 3000 |
+---------+------+
```

I can get the above result by using the following sql. However, I don't know is there any better approach or not. Is it necessary to repeat the same subquery twice? Thanks.

```
SELECT T1.user_id, T1.sum
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) as sum
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_id
) T1
WHERE T1.sum = (
  SELECT MAX(T2.sum)
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) as sum
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) T2
)
GROUP BY T1.user_id;
```

Comment: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties) check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can simplify your query to

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) as sum
FROM transactions
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(amount) = (      
  SELECT SUM(amount) as sum
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC 
  LIMIT 1
  )
```

Comment: Although it still uses LIMIT, it fulfills the goal I want to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: Well I assume you mean your LIMIT wasnt working, not that it was forbidden