# HOW to Find the most frequent string in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the most frequent car type (varchar) within the 25 years older owners. I wrote a query, but it counts all the types of names.
How can I complement this mySQL query to count only the same name type of cars?

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) 
FROM `car` 
INNER JOIN owner 
ON car.owner= tulajdonos.id 
WHERE 2018 - owner.birth_date >= 25
```

Comment: add `Group by Type` to teh end of your SQL statement. and LIMIT 1 or see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort descending your query and take only the topmost row with `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT type, COUNT(type) AS counter 
FROM `car` 
INNER JOIN owner 
ON car.owner= tulajdonos.id 
WHERE 2018 - owner.birth_date >= 25
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the one most frequent type you could use

```
SELECT top 1 type, COUNT(type) 
    FROM `car` 
    INNER JOIN owner 
    ON car.owner= tulajdonos.id 
    WHERE 2018 - owner.birth_date >= 25
    order by count(type) desc, type
```

if you are sure there are no ties.

Also, your way of determining age isn't perfect, you could use something like:

```
WHERE 
case
    when DATEPART(DY, owner.birth_date) > DATEPART(DY, GETDATE())
        then DATEDIFF(YYYY, owner.birth_date, GETDATE()) - 1
    else DATEDIFF(YYYY, owner.birth_date, GETDATE())
end >= 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by doing the date arithmetic correctly.  After that, you probably just want `limit`:

```
SELECT c.type, COUNT(*) AS counter 
FROM car c INNER JOIN
     owner o
     ON c.owner= o.id 
WHERE o.birth_date < curdate() - interval 25 year;
ORDER BY counter DESC 
LIMIT 1
```